# How to add a custom button to Alfresco share page body?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

I am new to Alfresco and using alfresco enterprise 6.0. I am trying to create a button which the user can click when he wants to join a site where he is not a member of.

eg: when the user use site finder and click on site xyz (where he is not a member of) page body of http://localhost:8080/share/page/site/sitexyz/dashboard? will have a button which he can click on to request to join the site.

I'm not too sure how to achieve this.

I had a look at the dashboard.ftl and dashboard.js and I think these two files needs customising to achieve this. Is there any other file that I need to look at?

Answer (score 1):

There is already a "Join Site" link. It is accessed by clicking the gear icon on the right-hand side of the page.

However, if you still want to create your own button, why not create your own custom dashlet that displays a button? The button could call a web script. The web script can use the API to add the logged in user as a member of the site.

This should be developed as a Share AMP. You should never change the files that ship with Alfresco. You could be making your life very hard when it comes time to upgrade.